# How to make the email notification header and footer in Laravel dynamic?

Tags: laravel, email, notifications

I've only been able to pass dynamic data to my email notification body, not the header and footer, as it seems these are static templates which one can't pass variables directly to. Can this be done at all? I want to customise the header to fit each tenant who receives an email notification.

```
/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $url = url('/invoice/'.$this->invoice->id);

    return (new MailMessage)
            ->greeting('Hello!')
            ->line('One of your invoices has been paid!')
            ->action('View Invoice', $url)
            ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

How can I pass additional variables and access these in the header and footer of the notification template?

L

Comment: Can you provide some codes, so that we can help with your problem.

Comment: Hi @ponpon i'm sending the link please check helpfully for you
https://medium.com/@adnanxteam/how-to-customize-laravel-5-4-notification-email-templates-header-and-footer-158b1c7cc1c. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found another solution which is not documented but works like a charm.

step 1: as you know, have your blade published in 'email.blade.php'

step 2: inside this blade file refer to:

```
@component('mail::message', compact('add your field here'))
```

step 3: now, it is magically accessible in default message.blade.php

```
{{ $name of the field}}
```

step 4: you just have to provide it:

```
new MailMessage())->markdown('notifications::email', [ 'name of the field' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
```

Then you do not need to set in session.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to accomplish this using Markdown method. Basically you need to publish the email templates using the laravel command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications

php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

then you need to access your Notification class and add the markdown method passing the default email template located in **/resources/views/vendor/notifications/email.blade.php** along with the data[] array for the with the dynamic content.

```
public function toMail($notifiable) {
    return (new MailMessage)
           ->line('Line of text')
           ->markdown('vendor.notifications.email', [
              'headerTitle' => 'Dynamic header title'
           ]);
}
```

now you have access to the $headerTitle variable inside your email.blade.php template file

```
@if(isset($test))
    {{$headerTitle}}
@endif
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how to pass additional variables (like a tenant name) to the default markdown views, when using just the `subject()->line()->action()->line()` methods and not the custom `markdown()` view method as per your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Set them in the session and retrieve them later:

```php
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    session()->now('arr', [
        'url' => url('/invoice/'.$this->invoice->id)
    ]);

    dispatch(function () {
        session()->forget(['arr']);
    })->afterResponse();

    $url = url('/invoice/'.$this->invoice->id);

    return (new MailMessage)
        ->greeting('Hello!')
        ->line('One of your invoices has been paid!')
        ->action('View Invoice', $url)
        ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

```
@component('mail::footer', ['arr' => session('arr') ?? []])
```

Now in the footer уоu can access the url as such `$arr['url']`.